# data structure for key value angular 5 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-datatables

I'm looking for a solution that can replicate a key/value dictionary in Python. I am using Angular 5 typescript for my project and I am new to the datatypes available. I have read a bunch of things online and it seems that because Angular is always changing, there are datatypes that are being depreciated or not supported anymore.

This is what I am trying to accomplish. If anyone can recommend a good resource to look at, I would greatly appreciate that.

**Python equivalent**

```
string = "the bump from the sump in the sump for the trump and the bump"


a = {}
for x in string.split():
    if x in a.keys():
        a[x] += 1
    else:
        a[x] = 1
print(a)

for b in a.keys():
    if a[b] > 1 and a[b] < 4:
        print(b)
    if a[b] >= 4:
        print(b)
```

Comment: **Angular is always changing, there are datatypes that are being depreciated or not supported anymore.** Don't understand why people bravely decided to jump onto Angular while being unfamiliar with the Javascript language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be written in TypeScript as below:

```
let string = "the bump from the sump in the sump for the trump and the bump";

let words = string.split(' ');

let wordCount = words.reduce(((acc, elem) => { 
  acc[elem] = (acc[elem] || 0) + 1; return acc;
}), {});

Object.keys(wordCount).forEach((key) => {
  if (wordCount[key] > 1 && wordCount[key] < 4) {
    console.log(wordCount[key]);
  } else if (wordCount[key] >= 4) {
    console.log(wordCount[key]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me understand the conversion. It's people like you who help people like me that are just starting out in their career to better understand how to improve our knowledge.

Comment: The only thing I found potentially wrong is that you have the reduce wrapped in an extra pair of () ?

Comment: I am passing default value for accumulator as empty object `{}` - it is second parameter to `reduce` method.   If you think you can get rid of `()` - give it a shot!

Comment: Right, I figured that out. But actually, reduce((acc, elem) => {
        acc[elem] = (acc[elem] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
        }, {});

this works too, after removing one set of ()

Comment: @dataviews I see what you mean.   - Being from Java background, I kept () thinking TS will complain

Answer (score -1):

You can use ES6 "[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)" data type:

Have a look at the article https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373.